# Identify BMX Bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

I have an old BMX that I don't know. I have serial numbers on the frame at the rear of the bike where the rear tire mounts.

The only identifiers I have for this bike are the serial numbers on the rear dropout, stickers that say 'Pro Sting'. Serial number on the bike is LY354 7400

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's vaguely possible that the bike was somehow produced by bike builder Alain Prost.  But more likely "Prosting" has to do with beer drinking.

Comment: Um, much more likely that it’s the Pro version of the Schwinn Sting, though it would be awesome if it were really about beer.

Comment: Please, help us help you - see https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: The combination of the loop tail and Redline like front gusset might be distinctive enough to identify the frame. In the pictures it is not clear exactly how the chain stays attach to the bottom bracket. It's hidden by the chain ring in the top picture. A better picture of the rear of the frame and the front gusset would help.

Comment: Could possible be an 80 - 84 Norco or Tioga, wont post as an answer as yet until I do some digging

Answer (score -5):

I think it is a Schwinn.

Look the serial number - that will tell you a year, then check archives of yearly catalogues for further information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack exchange.  I've edited your answer to make it more formal and less slang.    Please read [How do I write a good answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and also take the [tour] to learn how SE is organised.

Comment: I’ve searched in some of the Schwinn sites. The serial number doesn’t seem to follow the given formats, and it doesn’t show up in the databases people have made. Until you clarify, the answer does not appear to be correct.